# Unable to create Snowflake Free Tier Account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have not been able to create a free account on snowflake. I dont receive an activation mail after registering on the snowflake.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please reach out directly to support with your account specifics. https://community.snowflake.com/s/#SUPPORT

Comment: Sometimes it takes some time to receive email.